# Zero is out of range for data type SQL_VARIANT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

An automatic maintainence job on a SQL server, which amongst other tasks checks the integrity of all databases (by issuing the command `DBCC CHECKDB (blabla) WITH all_errormsgs, no_infomsgs, data_purity` for every database), throws the following error message (a few hundred times):

```
Msg 2570, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Page (1:235), slot 22 in object ID 643585431, index ID 1, partition ID 323652991516672, alloc unit ID 42178014806016 (type "In-row data"). Column "Value" value is out of range for data type "sql_variant".  Update column to a legal value.
```

After some forensics work I have found that it throws the message on all rows which has a column with the value `0`. When there is another value than `0` no error message is thrown. I have no idea how that specific value can be out of bounds for the data type `sql_variant`.

This database is a part of a commercial product which I have no design input in, and the maintenance job is a must for the company at which the server is installed. I am mostly just interested for the sake of knowing how come the database consitency check considers the value `0` to be out of range, to see if it is fixable. All errors are caught and sent to HQ, and therefore must be commented and responded to by some poor soul, so it would be nice to be able to avoid such meaningless errors.

The server OS is Windows Server 2012 Standard and the Microsoft SQL server version is 11.0.5058.0.

Comment: What's the data type of the column that throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of feels like a bogus error in `DBCC CHECKDB`, yet I can't believe the MSSQL engineers would put it in when there is no reason for it.

When I run below :

```
-- test database
CREATE DATABASE test
GO
USE test
GO
-- test-table
CREATE TABLE t_variant ( row_id int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,  variant1 sql_variant NULL, variant2 sql_variant NOT NULL)

INSERT t_variant (variant1, variant2) VALUES (1, 2), (NULL, 3), (NULL, 0), (0, 0)

SELECT * FROM t_variant
GO
-- see how things look 'on disk'
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM sys.partitions WHERE object_id = object_id('t_variant')
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM sys.allocation_units u JOIN sys.partitions p ON p.partition_id = u.container_id AND p.object_id = object_id('t_variant')

GO

USE tempdb
GO
DBCC CHECKDB (test) WITH all_errormsgs, no_infomsgs, data_purity
```

I seem to be reproducing the situation you describe, yet the `CHECKDB` does not give any warnings/errors.

```
-- having a look on the lowest level
DBCC TRACEON (3604) -- otherwise not output, just for this connection
DBCC IND ('test', t_variant, -1) -- shows the pages involved, I have 2 of them but from the error you have I'd focus on PageType 1 (data) only
DBCC PAGE ('test', 1, 515, 1) -- (= db_name, PageFID, PagePID, print-option-1)

-- the output is rather chinese but shows me the different slots (records) and their 'hex' information. I'm guessing that when you do
-- DBCC PAGE ('blahblah', 1, 235, 1) you may find some zero's there that DBCC CHECKDB thinks shouldn't be there...
```

Out of curiosity, what happens when you update the value to something else and then back to `0` ? [assuming you have an environment where you can test this out]